# Excel version of Skewed Normal Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to deskew some distributions based on checks that verify Skew and Kurtosis and within range, if not, I was going to attempt to deskew the data.

On wikipedia, there's a mathematical notation for the CDF of a skewed distribution.

Could someone show me how this would be setup in excel?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew_normal_distribution

Also, anyone know how this varies from a Box Cot estimated lambda distribution transformation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this version of skew normal will work for you. You already have some data, and you'd like to transform them to normality? Then Box-Cox is probably the first thing to try, but the data should be positive-valued. Also, you cannot fix both skew and kurtosis with these, only skew.

In fact, I wouldn't rely on skew alone, but make histograms of your transformed variables. Excel histograms are notoriously bad, maybe it's time you tried R.

Comment: Well can u answer my other post? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828868/cumulative-distribution-function-of-skewed-data

Answer (score 1):

If we want to plot the skew normal curve in Excel, we would use something like this:

The skew distribution curve is 
$$f(\alpha,x)=2 \phi(x) \Phi(\alpha x)$$

Where (in almost-Excel)
$$\phi(x)=normal~distribution(x)=norm.dist(x,0,1,False)$$
and 
$$\Phi(x)=cumulative~normal~distribution(x)=norm.dist(x,0,1,True)$$

So combined, we get (still in almost-Excel)
$$f(\alpha,x)=2*norm.dist(x,0,1,False)*norm.dist(\alpha*x,0,1,True)$$